# Using dll simultaneously from two separate executables

Tags: dll

Actually my question is more related to dll.

- I have one application GUI (name:  `xxx_app`)
- I have second application GUI (name:  `AAA_app`)

Both of which can tx/rx data from zanthric USB-2-CAN device using dll directly.

Now is it possible for both **AAA_app** & **xxx_app** to directly use same dll for zanthric device & operate simultaneously?

Is it possible for both GUI to load same DLL for communication?

Will it cause some problems will tx & rx of data in two GUI?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an important question. I believe it depends on the DLL and the USB driver you activate. I know that a USB DLL/driver that I used made problems when accessed simultaneously even from the same application by 2 threads. I had to synchronize the access using semaphores.

The TCP/IP stack, on the other hand, is intended to work simultaneously with multiple processes. It's a matter of both hardware and the software above it.

Unlike TCP/IP, there is no standatd "USB stack". So it depends on the driver running the USB you use.

Comment: means driver will become complicated as it have to -- synchronize the access using some mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

It's entirely possible for multiple processes to use a single DLL - indeed that's generally how things work.

However whether or not it does what you expect, when accessing a hardware resource, it down to how that particular DLL functions. I'd expect at a minimum that there would be some level of access control going on at an API level.